# NTFS External Drive takes too long to takes data in Mac?

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I've an Seagate 500 GB external Hard Disk (NTFS). To read/write it on Mac (OSX 10.6.2) , I've tried MacFUSE and NTFS-3G to write my HD on Mac. Though I could be able to see the hard drive, it takes too long to see the contents like this

[image]

Is this normal? Data transfers take a long time and the hard disk becomes too hot.

Any suggestions and solutions are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a lot of files in that directory? The FUSE driver isn't really the fastest thing out there to be honest so listing the files may take a while, and depending on your ebook software, it may be trying to make thumbnails of the covers as well. How fast does an `ls` run from the command line?

Comment: yes. a lot around 10 GB. ls runs fast enough like accessing home directory

Comment: Try moving some files to subdirectories in the command line. That should make things more responsive.